# show input text after " Yes" in dropdown is clicked in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I want to use this dropdown in php, when the user click YES on limited time ?, then the page will automatically refresh and a new " Available " input type is out to enter the start date and end date of the limited time the user want. I don't know how to type the code . do i need to use javascript or i just can use php function tags in my code to solve this problem . anyone that might know can help me with this thank you :)

[example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T55cE.png)

I only use PHP and MySQL in my code

Here are some of my code

```php
<tr height="46">
   <td>Limited time?</td>
   <td>: 
      <select name="limitedtime">
         <option <?php if($ec_programme_expire=='0')echo 'selected'; ?>value="0">NO</option>
         <option <?php if($ec_programme_expire=='1')echo 'selected'; ?>value="1">YES</option>
      </select>
   </td>
</tr>    

<tr height="46">
   <td>Availability</td>
   <td>: 
      <input class="txtf" name="ef_date" type="text" id="datepicker"/> 
      to 
      <input class="txtf" name="def_date" type="text" id="datepicker2"/>
   </td>
</tr>
```

```
<script>
$(function() {
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", $( this ).val() );
   $( "#datepicker").datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
   });
});
$(function() {
   $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: "in PHP", this is not related to PHP, this is JS, try to be more clear in your questions and titles :).

Comment: @Asfo thank you for the advise i'll try to be more clear with my other questions and titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery can do that without refreshing the page.

You might need to add a id to your select element, then wrap your date picker to div element with ID. You can hide the date picker when page was loaded then show only when the user selects `yes`.

```js
$('#limitedtime').on('change', function() {

  if (this.value == 1) {
    $('#pickdate').show();
  } else if (this.value == 0) {
    $('#pickdate').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
#pickdate{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Limited Time? 
<select id="limitedtime" name="limitedtime">
  <option selected>Select</option>
  <option value="0">NO</option>
  <option value="1">YES</option>
</select>

<div id="pickdate">
 Availability: <input class="txtf" name="ef_date" type="text" id="datepicker"/> to  <input class="txtf" name="def_date" type="text" id="datepicker2"/>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, it run as perfectly like i want :)

Comment: Glad to help! Cheers!